# Vectorize a Left Join Loop

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am trying to turn a loop into an lapply call, but I am struggling with the syntax.

I have a dataframe with nothing but a date:

```
start <- as.Date("2020-03-25")
df <- tibble(date=seq(start,Sys.Date(),"days"))
```

I also have a large list, the elements of which are time series data with varying lengths. something like:

```
list_element_1 <- tibble(date=as.Date("2020-03-25"),x=1)
list_element_2 <- tibble(date=as.Date("2020-03-26"),x=2)
list_element_3 <- tibble(date=as.Date("2020-03-27"),x=3)

list <- list(list_element_1,list_element_2,list_element_3)
```

I want to easily merge the elements of the large left to the data range. I achieved it with this loop:

```
for(i in list) {
  .GlobalEnv=TRUE
  df <- left_join(df,i,by="date")
}
```

How do I do it with lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
c(list(df), list) %>%
       reduce(left_join, by = 'date')
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'date', all.x = TRUE),  c(list(df), list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a recursive option using `lapply` would not give the desired effect.

Using base R, we can do :

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE, by = 'date'), c(list(df), list))

#        date x.x x.y  x
#1 2020-03-25   1  NA NA
#2 2020-03-26  NA   2 NA
#3 2020-03-27  NA  NA  3
#4 2020-03-28  NA  NA NA
#5 2020-03-29  NA  NA NA
```

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I did not see it when posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
df_left_joined_list <- merge(df, do.call("rbind", list), by = "date", all.x = TRUE)
```